# How to make two grid responsive layout in tailwind css

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a two-column responsive layout with tailwind CSS where the first column will take up to 70% and both columns will become full width on mobile.
I have tried the below but it seems I am actually missing out on something and the results are not what I want.
Please I need someone to help.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" />

<div class="grid grid-cols-5 md:grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-3">
    <div class="col-span-4 flex justify-center text-6xl border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-xl p-6 bg-gray-100">2</div>
    <div class="flex justify-center text-6xl border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-xl p-6 bg-gray-100">4</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Tailwind is mobile-first, so `grid-cols-5` means 5 columns on mobile, and AFTER md-breakpoint it will be one column (`md:grid-cols-1`) - see here the [result](https://play.tailwindcss.com/W0dSHjo3rv) - toggle view switch at right top

Answer (score 2):

You can use grid-flow-row sm:grid-flow-col class for parent div and set sm for col-span-4 class, see the example below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" />

<div class="grid grid-flow-row sm:grid-flow-col gap-3">
<div class="sm:col-span-4 flex justify-center text-6xl border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-xl p-6 bg-gray-100">2</div>
<div class="flex justify-center text-6xl border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-xl p-6 bg-gray-100">4</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: dude, you rock! I love simple solutions like this.